# How to Bind different react components with the same react-router route depending on redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, frontend

Using React, Redux and React-router, I want to to bind different components to the same route depending on the redux state. for example:

Assuming ComponentA and ComponentB are React components

Assuming I have this redux state

```
{
  flag: true;
}
```

I want to have this React Router configuration `/routes.js`

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="/test" component={ComponentA} />
</Route>
```

but if I have the `flag` in my Redux state to be `false` I want to have

```
...
  <Route path="/test" component={ComponentB} />
...
```

I am aware that I can create a wrapper component to `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` that checks the redux state and then render the corresponding component, but I was searching for an answer that doesn't require creating new components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a terinary operator in the component field of route.

```
<Route path="/test" component={flag ? ComponentA : ComponentB} />
```

Edit: This is how you would map the flag from your state to a prop.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// ... Component Definition

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    flag: state.flag
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    // Whatever you want to dispatch
  }
}

const ConnectedComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(YourComponent)
```

Edit 2: Connecting React Router to Redux using a `Provider`

```
const Root = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)
```

Comment: How do you get the flag from the redux state ?

Comment: That depends on how the rest of your project looks, but in general you would use the `connect` HOC from `react-redux` and map the flag prop in the mapStateToProps function it takes as an argument.

Comment: I edited my answer above to show how this can be done.

Comment: the `<Route> ..` is in another file so basically if I do `flag? ..` flag is undefined

Comment: If you want to use the redux state to determine your routes you have to connect it somewhere. I don't know the architecture of your project so I can't tell you where to do this. As long as you have your `Router` wrapped in a `Provider` component you should have access to the redux store. You should have something that looks like what I put in my second edit that will allow you to access the state in your route handlers.